# Please advise on the order of calculation

Tags: functions

I have to make a software making the calculations below over some set of data. That is basically not a problem. The problem I have is with notation of the second formula which is the (Utility function). In the notation given do I make the SUM operation with "Ank * Dummy k" and than to this sum of that expression for all "k" I add the "Bn * Price jt"? Or I am supposed to make the SUM for all the expression "Ank * Dummy k + Bn * Price jt" for all "k"? I.e. my problem is with priority of operands. If the SUM operand is the lowest priority than the second guess is right. If not, then I whould expect some brackets indicating what should I SUM while iterating "k". But I don't have any brackets in this expression. Please advise on the order of calculation.

Initial formula is:

$$P_{njt}=\dfrac{e^Unjt}{\sum\limits_ke^Unkt}$$

Utility function is :

$$U_{njt}=\sum\limits_k \alpha_{nk}\cdot Dummy_k+\beta_n\cdot Price_{jt}$$

PS: Also is there any way to simplify the expression?

Answer (score 1):

The notation is ambiguous. They should write either $\sum_k(a_k+b)$ or $(\sum_ka_k)+b$ so you wouldn't have to guess what they mean. But the chances are they mean $(\sum_ka_k)+b$.

Comment: I don't understand you. Do you understand my answer? Do you have a question about it?

Comment: The question you asked was whether the term after the plus sign was to be summed or not. I answered you. So are you now raising a new question, about whether $a_k$ has any meaning outside of $\sum_k$?

Comment: It seems to me that the terms with $\alpha$ and Dummy cancel, and you get $$P_{njt}={e^{\beta_np_{jt}}\over\sum_ke^{\beta_np_{kt}}}$$ where I've written $p$ for Price.

Answer (score 1):

There are no strong conventions on precedence when it comes to the $\sum$ operator, so the notation is ambiguous.

Your initial formula simplifies to:

$$\frac{e^Unjt}{\sum_ke^Unkt}=\frac{(e^Unt)j}{(e^Unt)\sum_kk}=\frac{j}{\sum_k k}$$

Further simplification may be possible depending on the range of summation.